# Why can't I load more than 100,000 Features from a WFS-Layer in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wfs, features

I want to have all the trees in Berlin as Shapefile. But I only get the first 100,000 trees.

This is the information about the WFS-Layer: http://daten.berlin.de/datensaetze/baumbestand-berlin-stra%C3%9Fenb%C3%A4ume-wfs

This is the WFS-Adress: http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/geometry/senstadt/re_strassenbaeume/?service=wfs&request=GetCapabilities

In the Parameters I changed f.e. the constraint for max features from 100,000 to 900,0000 or 1,000,000 but the result is the same.

[image]

Comment: There may be a maxfeature limit on the server side.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be a constraint of the WFS. It will always default to 100000.
 `<ows:Constraint name="CountDefault">
<ows:NoValues/>
<ows:DefaultValue>100000</ows:DefaultValue>
</ows:Constraint>`

Don´t know a way to do it in ArcMap other than you tried.

But you can try to download them via browser if you need them all. The Bad thing is that it does not recognise the StartIndex Operator where you could just download the first 100k and then the next 100k. But you can use probably the ALK_Nr4st field as a Filter and filter them via this field of the output data. As i don´t have any idea how the number is set (dublicates or not) it might be quite a few requests to be sure to have them all. It seems to be the only number in the output data that is may be uniqe. Alternativly you could try other filters like tree species or year planted and load all from year 2016 and then 2015 and so on. But it is quite a lot of work and the Maximum features of 100000 is still a constraint.

`fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/geometry/senstadt/re_strassenbaeume/?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=re_strassenbaeume&Count=100000&Filter=<Filter><PropertyIsBetween><PropertyName>ALK_Nr4st</PropertyName><LowerBoundary>0</LowerBoundary><UpperBoundary>200000</UpperBoundary></PropertyIsBetween></Filter>`

You can change the boundaries from 0/100000 to 100000/200000 and so on. You will always get the gml file that you can merge afterwards.